# I want to get back into 2D games programming

Tags: 2d

I used to develop games in the late 80's / early 90's and would like to look at getting back into it these days.

I have seen online there are so many options and libraries etc, so just thought I would try asking on here to see if anyone could offer some advice/a path to take.

I only really want to do 2D games as I did many years. I have seen things like Unity and other javascript libraries and it looks a bit of a minefield.

Ideally I would like to target Android / IPhone games.

I know c#, some c++, javascript/html5

Any info greatly appreciated.

C

Comment: Questions such as "how to get started" or "what to learn" are considered off-topic

Comment: We don't answer such questions exactly because there are so countless many options. So questions about which options to use just end up in discussions about personal preferences. This is not the kind of question we answer here. We only answer questions where the answers can be proven right or wrong, not where everyone is entitled to their opinion.

Comment: I wouldn't say only questions with "provably" right/wrong answers get accepted here — for instance, game design problems rarely have such objectivity — but we do need enough to be able to distinguish a "working" solution. For questions about how to get started or what tech to use, just about any answer qualifies as "working" so as described above they attract a lot of personal opinion & debate, and not a lot of consensus. A site designed as a discussion forum like GameDev.net is usually better-suited for this than a Q&A site focused on solutions.

Comment: The question is off topic, and the answer is Unity C#.